# How to skip timer interrupt while debugging Linux?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, interrupt

I'm trying to debug Linux source code using gdb+qemu solution.

I successfully compiled a debug-able kernel and connected to gdb.

However, when I'm trying to debug NVME part, the debugger acts as the follow:

1. Break at the target line performs OK.
2. "n": Nest step, "s": step in will immideatly jump to APIC timer interrupt.
3. Set a break point after (e.g first bp at line 100, second at 101), the program will only break at the first.

Thus I would like to ask how to avoid the debugger jump into the timer interrupt each time.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem and struggled many hours of trial and error. Below options solved my problem.

```
make menuconfig
> Processor type and features >
[*] Support x2apic

> Processor type and features > Linux guest support
[*]   Enable paravirtualization code
...
[*]   KVM Guest support (including kvmclock)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, was having the same problems, this solved the issue. However, can you please expand on how you reached at this solution?